# Is there an R function to select specific row numbers?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning

I'm a beginner in the process of learning R and I have a dataset containing book names and authors that I'm using as practice for cleaning data. In part of the process, I want to seperate the column "author" into "first_name" and "last_name".

When I perform this task, I get the following message:

```
library(tidyr)

#   - Seperate author first and last name
separate(df, col="author", into = c("first_name","last_name"), sep=" ")

Warning message:   
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in
18 rows [4, 12, 16, 17, 21, 23, 28, 34, 41, 43, 46, 60, 65, 67, 73,
79, 82, 84].
```

Looking back at the data, I can see that the error mostly occurs with Authors who have a middle name or middle initial (ex. Louisa May Alcot). I want to look up the rows stated in the warning message to remove additional spaces before cleaning. Is there a way to do this?

I tried using

```
df[4,12,16,17,21,23,28,34,41,43,36,60,65,67,73,79,82,84]
```

but I got an error message because R was trying to pull those up as columns and the dataset does not have that many columns. I've looked through some search boards for the code I would need to perform this task, but I'm being met with solutions that don't quite apply to the problem and seem more involved than they need to be.

Is there a simple way to resolve this problem? Or a different way I should be approaching the data?

Comment: Hi, please make small [self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), ty.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Caitlyn Manfre! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: It looks like you're using `tidyr::separate`, in which case in addition to providing sample data, you should add the [tag:tidyr] tag; if not, please be specific about non-base packages. Thanks!

Comment: perhaps the simplest thing would be ... `tbr_no_nulls[c(4,12,16,17),]`, using `[` as the extractor/accessor, which (for data frames) has two "arguments": the first references rows, the second references columns. So `dat[i,j]` subsets the data frame `dat` by the rows referenced by `i` and the columns by `j`. What I did with `c(..)` is to create a vector of constant row numbers. Depending on your data, it might be more robust to use something inherent in the data itself, but ... perhaps that's cart-before-the-horse. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think if you are trying to split a name variable into multiple columns where there may be more than one space there are other tools that you could use rather than trying to capture the rows that do not fit your use of `separate`.

Comment: Note, in R the syntax to select rows would be to pass a numeric vector of row indices which you create using `c`: `df [c(4,12,16,17,21,23,28,34,41,43,36,60,65,67,73,79,82,84),]`. Notice the `,` at the end. When extracting from a data frame(e.g., `[`) the first position is used to specify rows, after the comma would be to specify columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, here is an example of what I mean:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(name = c("Jane Doe", "Louisa May Alcot")) 

df |>
  mutate(last_name = sub(".*\\s", "", name),
         first_name = sub("(.*)\\s(.*)$", "\\1", name))

#               name last_name first_name
# 1         Jane Doe       Doe       Jane
# 2 Louisa May Alcot     Alcot Louisa May
```

Using regular expressions we can capture everything after the last space (`last_name`) and everything before the last space (`first name`). In some cases this will not work, for example "Vincent van Gogh". Here there is a space in the last name -- just something to be aware of if using this.

I think `separate` works nicely when you have consistent delimiters, but here some folks have three spaces while others only have two. Still you could force it using some logic like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  separate(name, into = c("first", "middle", "last")) |>
  mutate(last = coalesce(last, middle),
         middle = ifelse(last == middle, "", middle),
         first = trimws(paste(first, middle))) |>
  select(-middle)
```

Lastly, if as you mentioned in your post it makes sense to remove the space in this circumstance you could do that like so:

```r
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(name = ifelse(str_count(name, "\\s") > 1, str_remove(name, "\\s"), name)) |>
  separate(name, into = c("first", "last"))
#       first  last
# 1      Jane   Doe
# 2 LouisaMay Alcot
```